# how to bold a text in message template in format string c#

Tags: c#, .net, format-string

How do I make "Code" bold in the message below?

Code: {1}
Creation Date: {2}

results:

**Code**:123
Creation Date: 123

Comment: In what markup/encoding? Plain text doesn't know the concept of "bold".

Comment: I want to use this in a telegram Bot

Comment: https://telegrambots.github.io/book/2/send-msg/text-msg.html indicates you can use either html or markdown. But you need to set the parse mode accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can add bold tag <b> from c# to first part of string like below

 string stringA = "abc";

                string stringB = "123";

                string stringC = "xyz";

                string Final = "<b>" + stringA +"</b>" + stringB + stringC;
If you want to have a more generic approach you can create a method like below

/// <summary>
        /// Formaatedstrings the specified mainvalue.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mainvalue">The mainvalue.</param>
        /// <param name="partvalue">The partvalue.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string formaatedstring(string mainvalue, string partvalue)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(mainvalue, partvalue, @"<b>$0</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
and then call above method like below

var result = this.formaatedstring(Final, stringA);
```

Comment: Or you can use simple string interpolation. `$"<b>Code:</b> {code}
Creation Date: {date}"`